# How to can I make an input completely case insensitve (covering all possible variations)

Tags: python, case-sensitive

new starter here. I'm trying to run a simple guessing game where the input from the user wont be case sensitive, so i want the user to get the "you win" result regardless of inputting "Lion", "lion", "LiOn" etc.. i tried everything i could think about and failed. thank you.

```
secret_animal = "Lion"
guess = ""

    while guess != secret_animal:
        guess = input("Guess the secret animal: ")
        if guess != secret_animal:
            print("Bad luck try again")
            print("Hint: Some call it the King")

print("You guessed it!! YOU WIN")`
```

Comment: Convert your input and the target to the same case(uppercase or lowercase)

Comment: even better with `str.casefold()`

Comment: Thank you all, casefold, upper or lower all worked. I was forgetting to shift f10 and it kept failing, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of doing this is to set both guess and the secret_animal to lower case and then compare them. You can do this by using the .lower() function.

```
secret_animal = "Lion"
guess = ""

while guess.lower() != secret_animal.lower():
    guess = input("Guess the secret animal: ")
    if guess.lower() != secret_animal.lower():
        print("Bad luck, try again")
        print("Hint: Some call it the King")

print("You guessed it!! YOU WIN")
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, i also tried casefold and upper and all worked.